# Can I access private variables in an override version of this JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I am working with some JavaScript that a colleague wrote and need to override one of the functions in another script file that will be loaded after the first.

I think the problem is that the function I want to override is part of a return object within an immediate function so I cannot access 'private' variables that the original uses in my overridden version as they are out of scope by that point.  Perhaps and example would help.  The structure looks like this:

```
(function(){
    // stuff here
    $.obj=(function(){      
        var initialized=false;
        return {                    
            init:function(){ \\ stuff here}                 
         }      
    }()
})();
```

In my override I want to do something like:

```
$.obj.init = function(){ 
    // different implementation but with access to value of 'initialized'
}
```

Is there a way that I can achieve what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Nop, you can't access `initialized` form the outside without modifying the original code.

Comment: Thanks, ok, what about if I did modify the original code, how would I go about that?

Comment: It looks like you have an extra opening parenthesis by `$.obj=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to make the private variable accesible:

```
(function(){
    // stuff here
    $.obj=(function(){      
        this.initialized = false;
        return {                    
            init:function(){ \\ stuff here}                 
         }      
    }()
})();
```

so you can access it later:

```
$.obj.init = function(){ 
    // different implementation but with access to value of 'initialized'
    this.initialized = true;
}
```

But be aware that, for this to work, you need to create an object. I mean, you need to call `obj` like this:

```
var newObj = new $.obj();
```